# Using a Bootstrap theme with Flask-Bootstrap

Tags: python, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-bootstrap

I'm new to UI web development with Flask and have tried some sample projects with Flask-Bootstrap. Is it possible to use a custom Bootstrap "theme" with Flask-Bootstrap? I'd like to use this theme for my website: https://github.com/kristopolous/BOOTSTRA.386

But because I'm relatively new to UI stuff/JS/CSS, I can't tell if it's possible to use the Bootstrap.386 theme with Flask-Bootstrap.

Can anyone with experience tell me this if this is technically feasible and maybe point me towards a tutorial or something where someone has done similar? I haven't had much luck with Googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask-Bootstrap has a built-in base template with some pre-defined macros, you can rewrite the `styles` macro to use your own Bootstrap CCS files.

Suppose you have downloaded the Bootstrap theme file, it will contain the main CCS file called `bootstrap.min.css`. Put this file to your `static` folder. Then overwrite the `styles` macro in your base template to include it:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

{% block styles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='path/to/your/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
{% endblock %}
```